# MS Access/ADO AddNew method not appending record

Tags: ms-access, ado.net

I'm using ADO 2.1 in MS Access 2003 and calling the AddNew method of an ADO recordset using an array of field names and an array of values. I am getting no error messages however, the record is not being written to the table.

I have tried following the command with a .Update and a .Requery to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
Public Function ReadFileViaTextStream(ByVal PortfolioName As String, ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal TargetTable As String, _
                                                    ByRef TargetFields(), ParamArray SourceFields() As Variant)



Dim p_adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ForWriting() As Variant

Set p_adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset

p_adoRS.Open TargetTable, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable

If p_adoRS.Supports(adAddNew) Then
    p_adoRS.AddNew TargetFields(), ForWriting()
    p_adoRS.Update
    p_adoRS.Requery
End If
```

TargetTable is a string parameter, TargetFields is an array of field names and ForWriting is an array of values.

Answer (score 3):

Right - Myself and a colleague have found the issue. The recordset should be opened as adLockOptimistic, not adLockBatchOptimistic.

Comment: This was helpful! In my case I didn't realize the opposite, that adLockBatchOptimistic was required. Using adLockOptimistic prevented my disconnected recordset from doing a batch update. Thanks.